# How to solve the captcha enterprise?

Tags: python, recaptcha, captcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I need to pass the captcha in steam, captcha kind Recaptcha v2 Enterprise, used the service 2recaptcha.com to pass the captcha, displays an error ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE, the site itself is written that may require additional parameters such as the parameter s. I will show my code as an example:

```
def solve_recaptcha(data, url):
    solver = TwoCaptcha(api_2captcha)
    try:
        result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey=data["sitekey"], url=url, enterprise=1, datas=data["datas"])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error during captcha solution: {ex}")
    else:
        return result
```

At first I made a mistake and didn't notice that captcha enterprise, captcha was solved but steam gave me an error, now when I started solving captcha like enterprise captcha, 2recaptcha site gives me an error.
What is my error and how can I solve it?
If I'm not using the right tools, which ones should I use?

Comment: **Error description**  : We are unable to solve your captcha - three of our workers were unable solve it or we didn't get an answer within 90 seconds (300 seconds for reCAPTCHA V2).
We will not charge you for that request.  **Try this action** :You can retry to send your captcha.

Comment: I know the meaning of the error. How can I solve my captcha?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is trying to re-call the function when you get an "ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE" error. Instead, you need to handle the exception and simply return an error.

You should also try other tools such as AntiCaptcha, DeathByCaptcha or DeCaptcher. These tools also provide reCAPTCHA v2 Enterprise captcha solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a while loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey=data["sitekey"], url=url, enterprise=1, score=0.3)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error during captcha solution: {ex}")
    else:
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code. The error ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE means that the captcha was not successfully solved. It's a normal error. List of errors: https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#error_handling

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

def solve_recaptcha(data, url):
    solver = TwoCaptcha("your API")
    try:
        result = solver.recaptcha(sitekey=data["sitekey"], url=url, enterprise=1, datas=data["datas"])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Error during captcha solution: {ex}")
    else:
        return result
```

The other problem I am facing is that on the Steam website, there is no 'submit' button under reCaptcha. Don't know how to pass it yet.

There is a tutorial on 2captcha website.
https://2captcha.com/2captcha-api#solving_recaptchav2_new
On their demo page where you solve a captcha, there is a submit button.